# How to convert a list into a tuple in Groovy?

Tags: list, groovy, tuples

Question: Let's say we have a `List<E>` in Groovy. How can we convert it into a `Tuple<E>`?

As beginner in Groovy, I could not find the Groovy equivalent of the following Python code:

```py
a = [1, 2, "three"]
b = tuple(a)
print(b)
# (1, 2, 'three')
print(type(b))
# <class 'tuple'>
```

Two ways, which seemed plausible, did not return exactly the same results:

```java
a = [1, 2, "three"]

// First way, cast as
b = a as Tuple
print(b)
// [[1, 2, three]]

// Second way, asImmutable()
b = a.asImmutable()
print(b)
// [1, 2, three]
b.getClass()
// class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
```

So, `as Tuple` returned a tuple containing the original list as a single element, whereas `.asImmutable()` returned an `UnmodifiableRandomAccessList`, which is almost like a tuple but not a tuple.

Is it not possible to create a tuple from a list in Groovy? If it is, how can it be done?

Comment: "Is it not possible to create a tuple from a list in Groovy?" - It is.  If you started with `a = [1, 2, "three"]`, what characteristics would you like the resulting Tuple to have?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown this was a simple example to demonstrate the issue not the use-case. In a realistic case one could create lists, rather flexibly as they are mutable, do certain checks etc and then return an immutable tuple for downstream processes. For the behavior, `UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` is in this case OK - as long as the downstream processes do not complain about not receiving a tuple. So, simply, I was hoping to convert a list into a tuple, just like in the Python example I provided.

Comment: Do you mean `new Tuple(*a)`

Comment: what other than an immutable collection should `asImmutable()` return? a Mickey Mouse?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, thank you very much for your simple and constructive comment. This was exactly what I was trying to achieve. Would you like to convert that into a small, proper answer for the Groovy beginners like myself?